# How to keep the image onto the screen?

Tags: java, applet

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.Component;

public class ImageExample3 extends Applet
{
private BufferedImage img;

int counter = 0;
private BufferedImage next2;
Point lll;
public void init ()
{
    resize (500, 500);
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL (getCodeBase (), "Pacman.png");
        img = ImageIO.read (url);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
    repaint ();
}


public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        g.drawImage (img, 0, 0, null);
        Dimension appletSize = this.getSize ();
        lll = getLocationOnScreen ();
        try
        {
            next2 = new Robot ().createScreenCapture (new Rectangle (lll.x, lll.y, 500, 500));
        }
        catch (java.awt.AWTException e)
        {
        }
        g.drawImage (next2, 0, 0, null);
        System.out.println (lll);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

}

What I am trying to do is to load a picture and then paint it, and then in the paint method, I used a point to tell me the location of the applet window on the screen and take a screenshot of it and then draw it on the applet. However, I want this to happen only once so I add a counter but whenever I run it, it draws the image and then gets replaced by a white box. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Call `super.paint` before you do anything else. Consider using a `JApplet` and do you custom painting on `JPanel`, you get the benifit of double buffering out of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen constantly needs to refresh. To show graphics, it paints an image every time the screen refreshes by calling the `update` method. The update method clears the screen by painting it white. Then, the `update` method calls the `paint` method (or `repaint` depending on context).

Because you only paint graphics once, your graphics are painted over by a blank screen and not refreshed. You need to paint your graphics *every* time that the screen refreshes, or they will be erased.

**Always** paint, but only take the screenshot once. Here's an example of the paint method:

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{

    g.drawImage (img, 0, 0, null);
    Dimension appletSize = this.getSize ();
    lll = getLocationOnScreen ();

    if (counter == 0) //try taking the screenshot when counter is 0
    {
        try
        {
             next2 = new Robot ().createScreenCapture (new Rectangle (lll.x, lll.y, 500, 500));
        }
        catch (java.awt.AWTException e) {}
    }
    if (next2 != null) //if you took the screenshot and saved it to next2, draw it
        g.drawImage (next2, 0, 0, null);
    System.out.println (lll);
    counter++;
}
```